# Php smarty strip_tag allow specific tags

Tags: php, smarty

Is there any way to use strip_tags in php smarty like in default , to allow specific html tags to pass?

```
stip_tags($a.message,'<p><div>');
```

what is the equivalent in smarty ?

```
{$a.message|strip_tags}
```

Comment: you could use regex_replace instead. See: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Smarty 2.6.26 and `strip_tags` works with an argument specifying which tags to keep.

Try this:

**PHP:**

```
$string = "<b>not bold</b><iframe>iframe goes away</frame> <p>paragraphed</p>
                        <div style='color:green'>div kept.</div>";
$smarty->assign('string', $string);
```

**In the template:**

`{$string|strip_tags:"<p><div>"}`

`<p>` and `<div>` will not be stripped.

Comment: that I have old version and Im sure I do , delivered by amember , I tried that code before and did not work

Comment: Still not supported in 2.6.26 https://github.com/appfog/af-php-thinkup/blob/master/_lib/extlib/Smarty-2.6.26/libs/plugins/modifier.strip_tags.php

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a bit late, but for those who needs to do this and don't want to write a Smarty-plugin:

In Smarty you can "borrow" methods from PHP, like this.

Instead of:

```
{$a.message|strip_tags}
```

use

```
{strip_tags($a.message,"<br><div>") nofilter}
```

*Note:* You only need the **nofilter** argument if you've set `$smarty->escape_html = true;`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tags.tpl), it is not possible to specify which tags to keep. However, you can easily create a plugin for yourself:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl